# Linq group + Join

Tags: c#, linq, join, linq-group

I've read some of the other questions, but couldn't get ans answer from them.

I'm a newbie in Linq. I have 3 tables.

City (id, name)

Specialty (id, name)

Quota (id, cityId, specialtyId, qty)

So, you have quotas for a specialty in a city. I'm trying to list this grouped by city. Something like this:

City: New York

- specialty A: 15
- specialty B: 12
- specialty C: 10

City: Paris

- speacialty A: 10
- speacialty B: 8

and so on.

Can someone help me with that?

**Adding Up**

I wasn't really asking for ready code. I think I should be more clear.

I can join the tables, by I'm confused how I'm going to group that by cities.

So for example, this will join everything

```
from cota in Cotas
join cidade in Cidades on cota.CidadeId equals cidade.Id
join especialidade in EspecialidadeMedicas on cota.EspecialidadeId equals especialidade.Id
select new { Qty = cota.Quantidade, City = cidade.Nome, Specialty = especialidade.Nome}
```

Obs: Language is portuguese, I translated the creation of the object, but Quantidade is Quantity, EspecialidadeMedica is Medical specialty and Cidade is City.

The result of this query is:

```
Qty | City       | Specialty 

10    Campinas     Pediatria     

15    Campinas     Cardiologia

5     Campinas     Ortopedia     

10    Sumaré       Pediatria                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

15    Sumaré       Cardiologia                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

14    Hortolândia  Cardiologia                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

5     Hortolândia  Ortopedia
```

I want to group that by the city, and be able to return an object which have city name and a List with Specialty and Qty.

Comment: Well, what you have tried? How much LINQ do you know? Is this LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework, ...?

Comment: Check it out http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b try something and post your code if you don't succeed

Comment: Do you know how to right the SQL for this query and just not how to convert it to LINQ?

Comment: I have added some code so you could see what I meant

Comment: Is entity framework. The example is using Linq to SQL because I'm using LinqPad for tests. But in the application itself I'll be using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've got what I needed by doing more research.

The code to achieve what I was looking for is:

```
from cidade in Cidades
join lista in 
        (
            from cota in Cotas 
             join especialidade in EspecialidadeMedicas on cota.EspecialidadeId equals especialidade.Id
            select new {
                CidadeId = cota.CidadeId, CotaId=cota.Id, Quantidade=cota.Quantidade,
                EspecialidadeId=especialidade.Id, Especialidade=especialidade.Nome
            }
        ) on cidade.Id equals lista.CidadeId into listaCota
select new {CityId=cidade.Id, cityName=cidade.Nome, quotaList=listaCota}
```

That way I have the following:

[image: Result from LinqPad 4]